# ViewEncapsulation creating problems while styling highcharts

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular2viewencapsulation

I am using a couple of charts in a single view, each chart being its own component. I have a LineChartComponent and a XRangeChartComponent. I am using a styles file with XRangeChartComponent and overriding some classes. But the styles are not getting applied in the chart.

After inspection, I found out that the styles file was modified by angular to append a class to conform to the shadow DOM. So, I used encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None in XRangeChartComponent. Now the styles are also getting applied for LineChartComponent.

How do I proceed?

The demo I am attaching has 2 line charts but it reproduces my issue.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-highcharts-styling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order for template elements to make use of component styles with view encapsulation, they should be created by Angular compiler. These elements are created by third-party library that accesses DOM directly and thus cannot be styled this way.

In order to be used with default `ViewEncapsulation`, styles should use [shadow-piercing combinator](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep):

```
:host ::ng-deep .highcharts-series-0 .highcharts-point {
  fill: #ff0000;
  stroke: #0000ff;
}
```

Comment: >>> and /deep/ are truly deprecated, since they were abandoned by native implementations. `::ng-deep` is current 'official' way and marked as deprecated to reflect that it isn't backed up by native implementations and won't work with `Native` view encapsulation. It won't be discarded until the arrival of a reasonable replacement.